# Extract deb file from an archive in bazel

Tags: bazel

I need to extract a deb file that is available inside an archive - in bazel

```
new_artifactory_archive(
        name = "extract",
        build_file = "//path_to_build_file:my_file.BUILD",
        path = "archive.tar.gz",
        repo = "https://repository_where_archive_is/",
        sha256 = "xxxxx",
    )
```

By default, Bazel extracted the archive, but I don't know how can I extract the deb file then.

*archive.tar.gz contains: deb_file1.deb and deb_file2.deb.*

I have to extract those deb_file*.deb files.

I tried to create a rule and I used something like 
`cmd = "cd to_path_where_debs_are_available && ar -x deb_file1.deb && tar -xf data.tar.xz"`

But I don't think this is the best approach.
Thank you!

Comment: Yep, that's pretty much it. You can write a nice rule and/or your own tool to unpack just content of deb on the fly, but `ar` -> `tar` is reasonably universal approach.

Comment: Thank you @OndrejK. ! But it doesn't work as expected because the output of the genrule can be a file (or more) and I don't know exactly the name of the files from deb_fileX.deb.